# How can I return data from a foreign table when querying the USER in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, key

For example, let's say my user table has a column that references a foreign table like HEIGHT. If I use:

```
return \Auth::user()->height_id;
```

in my controller I get the id of the primary key that is referenced in the HEIGHT table, but how can I retrieve the data that's inside the referenced row in the foreign table?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
return \Auth::user()->height()->YOUR_HEIGHT_TABLE_FIELD;
```

This is expected your already made the relations between your `User` and `Height` model. 
[Read More..](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated *again* per comments**

It depends on the the relations ship of user to height.

I assume that it is a user has only one height. If that is the case you would set up your user and height model like this.

**User**

```
class User extends Model {
    /**
     * The user's height
     * @see App\Height
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function height()
    {
        // if you break naming conventions you can specify a different key.
        // I am unclear because I do not know your db structure.
        // from docs:
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
        return $this->hasOne('App\Height');
    }
}
```

**Height**

```
class Height extends Model {
    /**
     * The height of a user
     * @see App\Height
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
```

}

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::with('height')->firstOrFail($id);
    return view('yourview')->with(compact('user'));
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $user->height->height }}
{{ $user->height->id }}
```

Whatever you do, I'd read [Eloquent: Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). It should be helpful.

**Addendum**

There are a few ways of doing this I can think of off hand. These will all result in a two queries, and I am pretty sure you can achieve this with one.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::with('height')->firstOrFail($user_id);
    return view('yourview')->with(compact('user'));
}
```

or

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $height = $user->height();
    return view('yourview')->with(compact('user'))->with(compact('height'));
}
```

or

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $height = Height::find($user->height_id);
    return view('yourview')->with(compact('user'))->with(compact('height'));
}
```

Comment: I get Undefined property: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$height` however the column is called 'height' in the table...

Comment: @Chriz74 updated per you comment. You should check out the docs, this is all in there and they are easy to read.

Comment: am I breaking naming convention? and shouldn't be `$this->belongsTo('App\User');` ?

Comment: If you are referring to another table you want to name the related key singular table name + `_id`. so in the `heights` table you would have `user_id` and in the `users` table you would have `height_id`

Comment: yes that what I have in my user table 'height_id' I have 'height' in Height table.

Comment: then I think you can just do `{{ $user->height->height }}`. You need to post more of your code if you are still having issues.

Comment: doesn't work, maybe I did not make myself clear. I am using `return \Auth::user();` and that returns me a json with all the data included 'height_id' which is the id of the row in the foreign table 'height' where I store the actual data, example 100cm .. so I want to get to 100cm and display that instead of the id.

Comment: @Chriz74 Good luck with this! Updated answer.